# connect a java program to mysql in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect a java program in netbeans using the mysql j connector i get an exception message saying `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` this my code

```
package testdb;

import java.sql.*;

public class Testdb {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/location";
        String login = "root";
        String pass = "";
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,pass);
            Statement s = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("select * from reservation");
            while(r.next())
            {
                System.out.println("id reservation = "+r.getInt("id_reservation"));
            }

        }catch (Exception e) 
        {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exception you get???

Comment: Print the stack trace  e.printStackTrace()  instead of the message. You will get a better idea. Check if you have added the required jar file to the build path

Comment: Don't use e.getMessage(). Use e.printStackTrace() to see a useful description of the exception.

Comment: change this line `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` to `e.printStackTrace()` and post here the full stacktrace

Comment: Remove your catch block, and add a throws XxxException to your main method (for each checked exception). Then paste the stack trace you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the exception says that it cannot find the Driver class of MySQL.

The `mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar` (or newer version, containing the class) has to be taken from MySQL. It has to be on the "class path" during run-time.

Nicest IMHO would be to have a **maven** project, then you could add a dependency with scope "runtime", and the jar would be taken automatically, and packaged in the resulting application.

Otherwise you can select the project's `properties`, `Libraries`, `Add JAR/Folder`, and add the self-downloaded jar (from mysql.org).

If you have a `target\myapp.jar` and a `target\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar` you may add a `Class-Path: ... lib\mysql-con...` entry in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in the `myapp.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add MySQL j Connectors jar to your classpath:

[Mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)